# How to animate all children of a container at the same time in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, storyboard

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone 8 using C#.

I have a layout of a gaming card and now I want to animate this card as a whole. My problem is when I start the animation it only changes the width of CardPanel (Stackpanel) and not of it's children, which are TextBoxes, Images and Shapes.

My general (simplified) structure is like this, trying to animate to turn around a card.

```
<Stackpanel x:Name="CardPanel">
    <TextBox x:Name="Title"/>
    <Image   x:Name="Image"/>
    <!--other elements-->
    <Storyboard x:Name="TurnCardSB">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CardPanel" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                         From="400" To="5" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                         AutoReverse="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Stackpanel>
```

Is there a smart way to apply this storyboard to all elements within this Stackpanel, instead of creating an Animation for all elements? 
Or maybe to freeze the layout and use it as one image (I find it a bit dirty this way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a smart way, **don't animate Width**. Its animating exactly what you told it to, and you will notice that if you just *manually* change the width of the panel (especially with `StackPanel`) that it doesn't scale the elements the way you expect.

Instead, use a `ScaleTransform` to actually *scale* the panel and its contents:

```
<Stackpanel x:Name="CardPanel">
    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
       <ScaleTransform x:Name=CardPanelTransform />
    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    <TextBox x:Name="Title"/>
    <Image   x:Name="Image"/>
    <!--other elements-->
    <Storyboard x:Name="TurnCardSB">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CardPanelTransform " 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" 
                         From="1" To="0.01" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                         AutoReverse="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Stackpanel>
```